# issue with Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.0.0** in my VS2010. and i checked in Manage NuGetPackages in that "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework" is showing as installed. But still getting error as

**"The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"**

Is there any solution for this.how can i fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445708/the-type-or-namespace-name-optimization-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-syste)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio:

Go to Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

Then:

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Pre

when i install this its working fine.